# How to understand this crash log? SIGSEGV

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, crash-reports

The app is crashing recently and I didn't manage to understand the crash log.

The crash happens only on iPhone 5s SDK:9.1, I can't reproduce it on simulator or other devices with other SDK versions..

```
Crashed Thread: 0
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x1993b5bdc objc_msgSend (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 28
1   UIKit                               0x18a45bfb4 -[UINibStringIDTable lookupKey:identifier:] (in UIKit) + 132
2   UIKit                               0x18a457c04 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] (in UIKit) + 48
3   UIKit                               0x18a339030 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] (in UIKit) + 1416
4   UIKit                               0x189fc01b8 -[UITableView _dequeueReusableViewOfType:withIdentifier:] (in UIKit) + 552
5   MyApp                               0x10028a160 -[HomeVC loadStandardContentCellOnTableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (in MyApp) (HomeVC.m:1604)
6   MyApp                               0x10028737c -[HomeVC tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (in MyApp) (HomeVC.m:1198)
7   UIKit                               0x18a1c220c -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] (in UIKit) + 688
8   UIKit                               0x18a1c2364 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] (in UIKit) + 80
9   UIKit                               0x18a1b17b8 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] (in UIKit) + 2440
10  UIKit                               0x18a1c6f0c -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] (in UIKit) + 104
11  UIKit                               0x189f5f22c -[UITableView layoutSubviews] (in UIKit) + 176
12  UIKit                               0x189e6f7ac -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] (in UIKit) + 644
13  QuartzCore                          0x18966eb58 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] (in QuartzCore) + 148
14  QuartzCore                          0x189669764 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) (in QuartzCore) + 292
15  UIKit                               0x189e862fc -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] (in UIKit) + 884
16  UIKit                               0x189f339e4 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] (in UIKit) + 1196
17  UIKit                               0x189f313bc -[UINavigationController _layoutTopViewController] (in UIKit) + 228
18  UIKit                               0x189f49fb4 -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] (in UIKit) + 728
19  UIKit                               0x189f49ca0 -[UINavigationTransitionView _notifyDelegateTransitionDidStopWithContext:] (in UIKit) + 416
20  UIKit                               0x189f499a8 -[UINavigationTransitionView _cleanupTransition] (in UIKit) + 744
21  UIKit                               0x189eaed3c -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] (in UIKit) + 312
22  UIKit                               0x189eacfb8 +[UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState] (in UIKit) + 324
23  UIKit                               0x189f3d4c4 -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] (in UIKit) + 1792
24  UIKit                               0x189f33098 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] (in UIKit) + 2696
25  UIKit                               0x189f32244 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] (in UIKit) + 868
26  UIKit                               0x189f31e6c -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] (in UIKit) + 60
27  UIKit                               0x189f31dd4 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] (in UIKit) + 208
28  UIKit                               0x189e6f7ac -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] (in UIKit) + 644
29  QuartzCore                          0x18966eb58 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] (in QuartzCore) + 148
30  QuartzCore                          0x189669764 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) (in QuartzCore) + 292
31  QuartzCore                          0x189669624 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) (in QuartzCore) + 32
32  QuartzCore                          0x189668cc0 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) (in QuartzCore) + 252
33  QuartzCore                          0x189668a08 CA::Transaction::commit() (in QuartzCore) + 512
34  QuartzCore                          0x1896620f8 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) (in QuartzCore) + 80
35  CoreFoundation                      0x184897bd0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation) + 32
36  CoreFoundation                      0x184895974 __CFRunLoopDoObservers (in CoreFoundation) + 372
37  CoreFoundation                      0x184895da4 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation) + 928
38  CoreFoundation                      0x1847c4ca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation) + 384
39  GraphicsServices                    0x18fa00088 GSEventRunModal (in GraphicsServices) + 180
40  UIKit                               0x189edcffc UIApplicationMain (in UIKit) + 204
41  MyApp                               0x100272ea4 main (in MyApp) (main.m:47)
```

I don't understand what is the real reason behind this crash. Any ideas?

Comment: I think there might be something wrong with your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in your `HomeVC`. You should make a breaking point when instantiating the cell, I think this is where the app crashes.

Comment: @StefanStefanov It's not crashing on my end. i can't reproduce this bug, I thought it may have some relationship with the old SDK or something..

Comment: I am pretty confident that something is wrong with the way you are dequeueing your cell. Maybe you are using a deprecated method for that?

Comment: @StefanStefanov This is the code I used for dequeueing the cell: `HomeContentCell * homeContentCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HomeContentCellID"];`

Comment: That's the problem. You should be calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. Otherwise your cell can be `nil`.

Comment: @Zakaria You used a deprecated method, as I thought, you should be using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` , else your cell can be `nil`

Comment: In which case it can be nil?

Comment: In the case that there hasn't been a cell already initialized with this `reuseIdentifier` the method will return `nil`

Comment: @Zakaria I just posted my comment as an answer. Can you please accept it if it solved your problem? :)

Comment: @StefanStefanov Alright, let me try and see if it worked.

Comment: @Zakaria Sure! Waiting for your response.

Comment: @Zakaria Did it work?

Comment: @StefanStefanov Still waiting for the testers to get back to me with feedbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a deprecated method for dequeueing your cell. Instead of using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` you should use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`.

Comment: I don't think it's actually deprecated, although certainly, it's easier to use the newer method because it always returns a non-null value.  In Swift especially, the difference is significant because using the forIndexPath variant means the result will not be optional so you don't have to unwrap it:

```    func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: String) 
    -> UITableViewCell?
 
    func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: String,
    forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
    -> UITableViewCell```

Answer (score 0):

SIGSEGV:- Its a segmentation fault. More details at [SegmentationFault](https://www.codechef.com/wiki/status-codes)

These methods below have the issue:-

`5   MyApp                               0x10028a160 -[HomeVC loadStandardContentCellOnTableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (in MyApp) (HomeVC.m:1604)
6   MyApp                               0x10028737c -[HomeVC tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (in MyApp) (HomeVC.m:1198)`

Put breakpoints in the loadStandardContentCellOnTableView and debug. The stack trace with other lines is related to apple methods.

Comment: It's not crashing on my end. I can't reproduce this bug, I thought it may have some relationship with the old SDK or something (I tested it on simulator with 9.1 SDK tho, and it works just fine)..